# Lebesgue Outer Measure confusion

Tags: real-analysis

I have just learned about the Lebesgue Outer Measure and am a bit confused about the definition.

So the definition is [image]

But I am unsure about how we take the infimum. I would greatly appreciate a few examples, especially simple ones just to be able to picture what is going on and how we take the infimum of a sum of lengths of intervals?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a concrete example of $E$ and try to find to what possible values $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \ell(I_k)$ can be. For example, when $E$ is the rational numbers, then set where the infimum is taken consists solely of the value $\infty.$

Comment: @WillM. Your advice is good but your example is wrong. The set of rational numbers has outer measure zero.  Indeed, any countable subset $\{a_k:k=1,2,\dots\}$ of $\mathbb R$ has outer measure zero, because it can be covered by intervals of arbitrarily small positive total length: Given any $\epsilon>0$, cover $a_k$ with an interval $I_k$ of length $<\epsilon/2^k$.

Comment: Any non-empty set $A$ of non-negative real numbers has an infimum. However, given a description of $A$, you may need a clever trick to determine what $\inf\,A$ is, e.g., see the example in @AndreasBlass's comment . I suggest you  look at very simple examples like single points and single intervals first of all.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's right. My bad, many years since I took measure theory and doing statistics makes one forget the foundations.